# testing an elasticsearch custom analyzer - pipe delimited keywords

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-6

I have this index with `pipe` as custom analyzer. When I am trying to test it, it returns every char, and not pipe delimited words.

I am trying to construct for an use case where my input line `keywords` looks like: `crockpot refried beans|corningware replacement|crockpot lids|recipe refried beans` and EL will return matches after it has been exploded.

```
{
  "keywords": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "cloud": {
        "properties": {
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "pipe"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "keywords",
        "creation_date": "1513890909384",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "pipe": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "pipe"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "pipe": {
              "pattern": "|",
              "type": "pattern"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "DOLV_FBbSC2CBU4p7oT3yw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6000099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I am trying to test it following this [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html).

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/keywords/_analyze' -d '{
 "analyzer": "pipe",
 "text": "pipe|pipe2"
}'
```

I get back char-by-char results.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "p",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "p",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "e",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work, you're almost there. Since the pipe `|` character is a reserved character in regular expressions, you need to escape it like this:

```
      "tokenizer": {
        "pipe": {
          "pattern": "\\|",   <--- change this
          "type": "pattern"
        }
      }
```

And then your analyzer will work and produce this:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "pipe",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "pipe2",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to rewrite the tokenizer without recreated the index?

Comment: You can update the analyzer in the index settings and then call update_by_query on your index and it will refresh the data

Comment: in order to update, I had to close the index, and apply the put to /_settings, then reopen the index, wait for shards re initialization

Comment: I am not sure it worked. I recreated the index, and the mapping and the documents as well. But still the document show up as text. I was expecting somewhere a tokenized representation. What I am missing?

Comment: The document you send to ES will never be modified in any way. however, the content of the document fields is what gets analyzed and indexed. Ultimately, whatever gets indexed is what will help you retrieve/search your documents. But don't expect ES to change the way your documents "look like"